# Which badminton speak is better in US `ba~d~min` or `ba~men~ton`

Tags: american-english

Badminton in google transalation speak like `ba~d~mon`
but I asked philippines friends they always speak like `ba~men~ton`
which one the US use in normal life?

Comment: Badminton is named after a place in England. It is _pronounced_ as it is written, 'BAD-min-ton'. I assume the American pronunciation Is approximately  the same.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks, but it's [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_m#en/zh-TW/Badminton) link, it's pronounce like 'ba~d~min',or just my wrong think.

Comment: Not to me - I can clearly hear the third syllable 'ton'. Yes, the 'min' is pronounced with an indeterminate vowel sound, more like your friends' 'men'.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks , colud you answer below , I'll mark it as answer!

Comment: no,thanks,this's another question.and Kate Bunting's reply is the answer

Comment: Google Translate alternates between saying the word quickly and saying it slowly. Try repeating at least it four or six times to see if you can start hearing all the syllables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Badminton (the game) is named after a place in England, pronounced as written, BAD-min-ton. In the Google Translate link provided, the American speaker uses a more indeterminate vowel sound in the second syllable, but all three syllables can be clearly heard.